# If the condition is false stop the script in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, the pop up is appearing but the AJAX part is also getting executed.

What I want here is, if the pop-up `$('#confirmCloseFutureEvent').modal('show'))` is executed I do not want the `$.ajax` call to run. I want AJAX to run if `ref == true`. How can I do this?

```js
function checkFutureEvents() {
  var result = false;

  $('.event-form-edit').each(function() {
    $endEventDateTime = $(this).find('.eventEndDateTime').val();
    $endEventDates = $endEventDateTime.substring(0, $endEventDateTime.lastIndexOf(' '));
    $currentDate = moment(new Date(), 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    $endEventDate = moment($endEventDates, 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    $eventStatus = $(this).find('.event-status option:selected').text();

    if ($eventStatus == 'Closed' && $endEventDate > $currentDate) {
      $('#confirmCloseFutureEvent').modal('show');
      $('#close-future-event').on('click', function() {
        listenerSaveModuleJob($(this));
      });
      result = false;
    } else {
      result = true;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  listenerSaveModuleJob();
});

function listenerSaveModuleJob($elt) {
  var res = checkFutureEvents();
  if (res == false) {
    return false;
  }

  $form = $elt.closest('.panel-default').find('form[class="job_modules"]');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: $form.data('action'),
    data: formSerialize,
    success: function(data) {
      //do-something
    }
  }
```

Comment: you can add to global variable as a state manager and check the state before running ajax

Comment: can u explain me a bit?